# How to create QQ plot in hvplot/holoviews?

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot

Does anyone know if Holoview/hvplot has an interactive QQ plot function to use? I found no material online about it. Or does anyone know how to plot an interactive QQ plot on holoview/hvplot? Found some content on [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/v3/normality-test/) however, I want to be consistent with using the same python library.